# Cucumber-guice: scenario-scoped interceptor?

Tags: java, cucumber, guice

In my cucumber tests I want to intercept some calls on the boundary of my system and then verify the arguments of these calls.

So in each scenario I perform some actions, my interceptors intercept the arguments of the calls to some external systems and store them in some class, let's call it `ScenarioContext`. Then these arguments are validated in my @Then step definitions.

The problem is that the `ScenarioContext` class has global `@Singleton` scope meaning many bad things, including inability to run scenarios in parallel, necessity to manually clean it up after each scenario, inadvertent dependency between the scenarios.

Cucumber-guice has a great feature called `@ScenarioScoped` annotation which allows me to have scenario-scoped classes and it works like a charm.

**My question**: is it possible to somehow make my `ScenarioContext` class (used by my interceptors to store the intercepted stuff) to be "scenario-scoped", i.e. to have it automatically cleaned up after each scenario etc.?

Answer (score 0):

A `@ScenarioScoped` dependecy that is injected by Cucumber into your step classes are always re-created for each scenario. Your job is to make sure you dont have any static fields in the injected dependency. Static fields belongs to the class and not the instance so they are not cleared for each new instance.

I write a [blogpost](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/08/16/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-guice) where I share state between steps with Guice which is what I think you are asking about.

Comment: Not precisely an answer to my question. I was already using `@ScenarioScoped` step definitions and it worked. The problem was that I had to use interceptors that always have a singleton scope and then I couldn't figure out how to connect singleton-scoped interceptors with an object that I wanted to be scenario-scoped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, just need to use the Guice injectors properly.

1. Guice allows to mix scopes via providers. So the solution was to add the following line to my cucumber-level Guice module: `bind(ScenarioContext.class).toProvider(ScenarioContextProvider.class).in(CucumberScopes.SCENARIO); /*ScenarioContextProvider - my own basic implementation*/` and then to pass this provider to the interceptors.
2. Additional complication is this: in my case the entire application was using its own Guice injector and the interceptors must be created there. But the `ScenarioContext` lives in cucumber Guice injector. So I had to explicitly pass the `Provider<ScenarioContext>` object to my application's Guice module.